# Why onDidChangeConfiguration not notified on time?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm using code like the following in my VSCode extension to be notified when a setting changes in settings extension page.

```
vscode.workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration(async(event) => await configMgr.onConfigurationChanged(event))
```

However, I found that the notifications for setting changes were not timely. Normally, the program will only be notified after modifying the settings after the command is triggered.

Any ideas on it?

Thanks.

Tried to used `async` and `await` keywords but doesn't work.

Notification should fires promptly after setting changes.

Answer (score 0):

Because my extension was not activated yet.
Add `"*"` to `"activationEvents"` in `package.json` fixed this problem.